# Difference between these two from design schemes of django

Tags: python, django

We can define a field in a django form in the following 2 ways:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    myfield = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(u.id, u.username) for u in User.objects.filter(type="TYPE1")])
```

AND also as

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    pass

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['myfield'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(u.id, u.username) for u in User.objects.filter(type="TYPE1")])
```

What is the difference between the two approaches (if any)?

Comment: They are effectively the same. The latter allows you to alter the field when the form is instantiated.

Comment: @Brandon I'm afraid they are not the same at all in this case...

Comment: Read your answer @brunodesthuilliers. Very informative, always great to learn something new about what you *thought* you knew :)

Answer (score 2):

There's a *very huge* difference...

In the first case, your `choices` will be eval'd when the class statement is executed, IOW when the module is imported, and will stay the same for the process lifetime. Since Django is usually deployed using long running processes, this means you will have stalled data, and also if you're deploying in a multi-process mode (which is often the case) you may have different sets of users for differents processes, hence inconsistant values from one request to another (eventually from the get to the post...).

To add to the fun, this kind of bug can be hard to debug since the dev server is running a single process and very often restarted...

In the second case, the `choices` list is created afresh each time the form is instanciated, so it's safe - and is of the course the right way to set dynamic choices (at least until 1.7.x included - IIRC 1.8 allow to pass a callable instead of sequence).

As a side note: loading the full models only to retrieve a pair of fields is not really efficient, you'd better use `Queryset.values_list()` here. Also, you don't have to (re)instanciate the whole field in the `__init__`, you can just declare the field as usual and rebind it's `choices` attribute later:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    myfield = forms.ChoiceField(choices=())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['myfield'].choices = User.objects.filter(type="TYPE1").values_list("id", "username")
```

And finally, you may want to have a look at the [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)
And finally

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    myfield = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(u.id, u.username) for u in User.objects.filter(type="TYPE1")])
```

This defines the field `myfield` and fetches the choices at the time that the class is defined. This isn't ideal, because it means you have an SQL query to fetch the choices from the database when the application loads. This will slow down the loading of the application, and the choices will get out of date as you add/remove users.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    pass

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['myfield'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(u.id, u.username) for u in User.objects.filter(type="TYPE1")])
```

This defines the field and the choices when the form is instantiated (e.g. in your view). This means that the choices will be up to date when you display the form.

Another option, and one that I recommend, is to define the field as usual, but set the choices in the `__init__` method.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    myfield = forms.ChoiceField(choices=())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['myfield'].choices = [(u.id, u.username) for u in User.objects.filter(type="TYPE1")]
```

You may also find [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) useful.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    myfield = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
```

Comment: Why do you recommend to set the choices in the __init__. Nothing wrong with it but I don't get why you feel it's better

Comment: Changing only the choices in the `__init__` method keeps all of the field definitions in one place. If you are using [model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform), then it prevents you from duplicating the field's definition.

Comment: @abrunet: adding fields in the initializer doesn't help wrt/ readability (one expects fields to be declared at the class level), and also some operations may depend on the field existing as a class attribute.

Comment: I'm well aware of that. It was just about the choices declaration in the init vs in the field definition that was ticlkling me. But your answer helps to understand. =)

Comment: Re: 'in the `__init__` vs field definition' -- that's what Bruno and I explain in our main answers (I think he does a better job). If the choices are dynamic, then **when** the choices are evaluated is really important.